# Logistic regression, use of lagged indicator counts as explanatory variable

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, feature-engineering, logistic-curve

I am an intern and new to make sas scorecard model. A former colleague tells me that, when selecting features for a logistic regression model, you better not choose ones that are related to the past value of the outcome.

E.g. in a model that predicts whether someone will buy stock, you should not use "the number times the stock was bought in past 3 months" as an explanatory variable.  The same would hold for e.g. "the total amount invested in stock for last week", ...

Is it correct that such explanatory variables are better not used in a logistic regression model, and if so, why is that ?

Comment: There is no  Question , I assume you want ton know whether you can include such features?

Comment: I just want to know if it is ok  I put such features to fit the model.and wht for it..

Comment: maybe it would be good to edit your question and add what you are asking there, because now it is put on hold by @Glen_b

Comment: @Glen_b I have already edit my question again,please check,thanks!

Comment: @fcop sir,I have already edit my question again.How could the question get recovered?

Comment: Please be patient. If your edit is sufficient your post enters a review queue and people will vote on it. It may take a while. I don't presently think it's sufficiently clear yet (I can't figure out what you want), but I will wait for others to make that determination. Meanwhile I encourage you to continue to do as much as you can to make it clear what the situation is.

Comment: It sounds like stupid advice. Normally past behaviour is a really good predictor of future behaviour.

Comment: @Bjorn: is 'normally' the same as always ?